# Record exact docker state per experiment

Tags: docker

I run my machine learning experiments with Docker on AWS.

I would like a way to track exactly what is inside each Docker image per training run.

For example, I could create a new Docker "tag" every training run and save this tag.

But that would require me to update the Docker tag in my YAML file each time... right now I just use "<docker_image>:latest" which always lets me use the latest Docker image.

I suppose every time I build, I could make two tags, "latest" and "random_string" and when I upload my experiment code to AWS I could save the most recent "random_string" to the config file of that experiment.

In summary, I just want a way to have exact reproducibility of my Docker image in a machine learning pipeline where the dependencies and code are constantly changing.

Comment: What are you referring to by "YAML file"? Docker compose file? Cloudformation stack file? Can you share that code?

Comment: Tags can be moved from image to image, an have less or no guarantee that specifying an image by tag will give you exactly the same result as it does tomorrow. 
So, I think you should try to use the image hash reference, because the hash is defined from the contents of the image. Any change to the image content results in a different hash.

Comment: I don't have code I can share, but basically, you need somewhere in your code that refers to the Docker image you want to use on AWS EC2. And I would prefer to not have a different "tag" every time that I need to programatically update.

Comment: @abestrad But ultimately I need to retrieve the image from the hash, which is not possible.

Comment: The hashes or digests are generated by Docker  `docker image ls --digests`. You use this hash to precisely reference a build (and specific dependencies)

Comment: So, @abestrad you are claiming dockerhub never deletes any image even when the tag is changed, and the hash can be used to always retrieve an image from dockerhub?

Comment: It is up to the image maintainers to retag images. Tags are mutable, so there is no guarantee a tag will never change. Pining-by-Digest guarantees that every instance of the service is running exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing two tags sound like the correct way for your pipeline, and for many pipelines.

But instead of "random_string" just push a "version_number" (e.g: "1.1.1")

Comment: ...or a date stamp ("20200714.01").